# How to access the console of Embedded Cassandra?

Tags: embedded-cassandra

I'm using [Embedded Cassandra](https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra) for some unit tests. I'm getting some unexpected error logs, so I'd like to inspect the database that's created to make sure it's what I think it should look like. Is there a way to open the Cassandra console while the test is paused at a breakpoint, like I can with H2?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure CassandraBuilder with your own WorkingDirectory and also configure WorkingDestroyer.

https://nosan.github.io/embedded-cassandra/4.1.0/#working-directory-destroyer

https://nosan.github.io/embedded-cassandra/4.1.0/#working-directory

Also, you can set a breakpoint before Cassandra.stop() method.

```java
cassandra.start();
try {

// queries



} finally{
//breakpoint here
cassandra.stop();
}
```

Comment: After hitting the breakpoint, how do I inspect the database?

Comment: I believe you can use any cassandra ui. You have address and port. And